# Excel is stripping leading 0's from CSV files

Tags: excel, csv, dataformat, autocorrect

It believe that Excel is stripping leading 0s. I was told that updating the column format to text during the export will fix this and to modify Excel output (coming from "ProofAndTracking actionIpromoteuAutomation" file, yet I can't find this file or how to access where the excel formatting code is generated).

I've never worked with Excel. I tried this, but it seems to be a local fix:
http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010262_Handling_Leading_Zeros_in_CSV_Files.html
Could someone point me in the right direction to start?

I've researched these answers [How to stop the leading 0's from being stripped off when exporting to excel from a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424412/how-to-stop-the-leading-0s-from-being-stripped-off-when-exporting-to-excel-from) and [Export Excel : Avoid stripping the leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574840/export-excel-avoid-stripping-the-leading-zeros)
Thanks in advance!

Here is the function I believe is causing the problem, but not sure yet how to format columns to text here.    /*
     * format and send order and tracking info (via Excel spreadsheet) for the day for ipromoteu (150837)
     */

```
public function actionIpromoteuAutomation() {
    $ordersGroup1 = $this->getIpromoteuProof();
    $ordersGroup2 = $this->getIpromoteuProofHistory();
    $orders = array_merge($ordersGroup1, $ordersGroup2);
    $fileName = 'Hit Promo Order Tracking ' . date('m-d-Y');
    $this->_export($orders, $fileName);
    $fileName = $fileName . '.xls';
    $toIPROMOTEU = array(//email to be sent to HR when request is submitted
        'body' => 'Attached, please find the Excel spreadsheet containing'
        . ' order details for orders on ' . date('m/d/Y') . '.',
        'from_email' => 'donotreply@hitpromo.net',
        'from_name' => 'Hit Promotional Products',
        'subject' => 'Order Tracking Information - ' . date('m/d/Y'),
        'to_emails' => 'orders@ipromoteu.com',
        'attachments' => array(array('path' => Yii::app()->basePath . '/../tmp/' . $fileName, 'filename' => $fileName)),
    );
    Hit::email((object) $toIPROMOTEU);

    $this->logForDeveloper('Order records sent to iPromoteU for '. date('m/d/Y'));
}

private function _export($data, $fileName, $format = 'excel', $output = false) {
    // get a reference to the path of PHPExcel classes
    $phpExcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel');

    // Turn off our yii library autoload
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
    include($phpExcelPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPExcel.php');

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    if ($format == 'excel') {
        // Set properties
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator(Yii::app()->user->name)
                ->setLastModifiedBy(Yii::app()->user->name)
                ->setTitle('Order Tracking Report');
    }

    $styleArray = array(
        'font' => array(
            'bold' => true,
            'underline' => true,
        )
    );
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    for ($rowCounter = 0; $rowCounter < sizeof($data); $rowCounter++) {
        $sheet->getStyle("A" . ($rowCounter + 1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
        $sheet->getStyle("B" . ($rowCounter + 1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
        $sheet->getStyle("C" . ($rowCounter + 1))->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
        $sheet->setCellValue("A" . ($rowCounter + 1), date('m/d/Y', strtotime($data[$rowCounter]['date'])));
        //$sheet->setCellValue("A".($rowCounter+1), $data[$rowCounter]['date']);
        if ($data[$rowCounter]['fedex_tracking'] != '')
            $sheet->setCellValue("B" . ($rowCounter + 1), $data[$rowCounter]['fedex_tracking']);
        else
            $sheet->setCellValue("B" . ($rowCounter + 1), $data[$rowCounter]['other_tracking']);
        $sheet->setCellValue("C" . ($rowCounter + 1), $data[$rowCounter]['sales_order_number']);
        $sheet->getStyle("B" . ($rowCounter + 1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
    }

    $sheet->setCellValue("A1", "DATE")
            ->setCellValue("B1", "TRACKING")
            ->setCellValue("C1", "PO NUMBER")
            ->getStyle("A1:C1")->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    ////Set the column widths
    $sheet->getColumnDimension("A")->setWidth(25);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension("B")->setWidth(25);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension("C")->setWidth(25);
    // Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Order Tracking Report');

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet,
    // so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $fileName = $fileName . ($format == 'excel' ? '.xls' : '.csv');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../tmp/' . $fileName;
    $objWriter->save($path);

    // Once we have finished using the library, give back the
    // power to Yii...
    spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
}

public function getIpromoteuProof() {
    $date = date('Ymd');
    $db2params = Yii::app()->params['db2params'];
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Db2', $db2params);
    $select = $db->select()
            ->from(
                    // table
                    array('t' => 'WBPIPRAE'),
                    // columns
                    array(
                'sales_order_number' => 'TRIM(WAESPO#)',
                    ),
                    // schema
                    $db2params['schemas']['hitdta'])
            ->joinLeft(
                    // table
                    array('f' => 'MFD1MD'), 'CONCAT(TRIM(WAEORD#),RIGHT(TRIM(MDORDR),3))=TRIM(MDORDR)',
                    // columns
                    array(
                'fedex_tracking' => 'TRIM(MDFTRK)',
                'other_tracking' => 'TRIM(MDFBRC)',
                'date' => 'TRIM(MDUPDT)',
                    ),
                    // schema
                    $db2params['schemas']['varfil'])
            ->where("MDUPDT = '" . $date . "'")
            ->where("WAEIVKY='150837'")
            ->order('sales_order_number')
            ->distinct(true);

    $stmt = $db->query($select);
    $orders = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $orders;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a fix on the export side? Also is the csv file being consumed ONLY by Excel or is it being read elsewhere?

Comment: Hi. Yes, apparently my co-worker thinks it's on export, and only being used by Excel.

Comment: Trying this code now, after mucho research!!  comments appreciated..  // Format columns as text to avoid Excel's nasty stripping habit-- Strips leading '0' from numbers.
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, Excel can create the csv columns as `text` but the issue is with the import.

When Excel opens csv files it 'helpfully' converts anything that looks like a number to a number, stripping leading zero's.

First make sure Excel is exporting it as it should, open the file in a text editor and check the leading zero is present.

You will probably have to change how the file is imported. Instead of them just double clicking the csv file, they need to run through the data import wizard:

**Import 'From Text'**

[image: From Text]

**Select Delimited**

[image: Next]

**Make sure comma is ticked**

[image: Comma separator]

**Select column as text**

[image: Select text]

This should resolve the problem on the other side.

Another alternative is to add a single apostrophe `'` before the numbers, however if they use macros/software to interact with the file this might break that.

**Edit**

After looking at the PHP code (I can't test) you might be able to change the line:

```
$sheet->getStyle("B" . ($rowCounter + 1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
```

To:

```
$sheet->getStyle("B" . ($rowCounter + 1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('000000000000'); // With however many zero's you need to keep
```

This however may still get removed when you export as it's still technically a number and formatting will be removed.

Comment: Did that, thanks, but I think that it is somewhere formatted in our php code and that I have to update the column format to text during the export.

Comment: @DR1 Is the leading zero missing when you open the csv file in a text editor?

Comment: Yes, that's why we think we need to format the columns as text.  Please see function above where I think I need to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm much closer to solving this now!

Comment: The single apostrophe did not work in LibreOffice. I am now using a TAB `\t` character as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15107122/119937).